How to use dipoles to enforce the boundary conditions for a spherical dielectric with complex permittivity
I want to impose an electric and magnetic field on a spherical dielectric of radius $ R $ and relative permittivity $\epsilon_r=\epsilon'+i\epsilon''$. Say the fields are slowly-varying (like a plane EM wave of wavelength $\lambda \gg R $). Assume the relative permeability $\mu=1$. Also, to make sure we're always in this slowly-varying/long-wavelength regime, assume that $ \lambda/n \gg R$, where n is the real part of the refractive index.
In the case that the imaginary part of the permittivity is zero, the boundary conditions can be enforced by approximating the sphere by a single electric dipole.
As the imaginary part of the permittivity approaches infinity, the sphere becomes "perfectly" conducting, and a resulting boundary condition is that electric field lines end on the surface of the sphere, and magnetic field lines must go around the surface of the sphere. I believe surface currents enforce this magnetic field boundary condition. This perfectly conducting sphere in a slowly-varying field is addressed by JD Jackson in section 10.1 of his book--he approximates it by one electric+magnetic dipole with appropriate dipole moments such that the boundary conditions are enforced.
In the situation when $\epsilon''$ is neither zero nor infinite, I have a feeling we could again approximate the sphere by an electric+magnetic dipole with appropriate dipole moments. The Clausius-Mossotti relation may be used to calculate the electric dipole moment. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to calculate the magnetic dipole moment?
